# Moving text whilst ::before element remains untouched

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a custom svg underline for a header. The result should be like this:

[image]

So far my code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="ml-4 underline-text">News feed</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.underline-text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    &::before {
        content: "";
        background-image: url("./../../dist/img/underline.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

Which results this:

[image]

How can I move the text without changing the underline position? Currently, it sticks to the very left start of the Bootstrap grid, and it is fine by me. However, I wanted to move the text a bit to the right. I tried applying ml-4, but it does not work at all. Meanwhile, mx-4 moves both the text and underline. The same happens if I set the margin-left in the CSS section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `margin`, use `padding` as this won't affect the position of the pseudo element.

```css
.underline-text {
  padding-left: 2rem !important;
}
```